# How HttpContext.Current works on each request in IIS pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pipeline, httpcontext

As you know, the [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the current context in the application pipeline.
Also this property is `static`, so logically any changes on that or on its properties should affect the other pipelines.

> A static field identifies exactly one storage location. No matter how
>   many instances of a class are created, there is only ever one copy of
>   a static field.
>   [More](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh0bL.png)

How IIS handle this to prevent conflict on the other pipelines and every `HttpContext.Current` be unique on each pipeline?

For example for two users that already logged into the system, the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` gives the username of the user who sent the request to the server.

ASP.NET Pipeline:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Current` is the property, not field, so it's a static method actually.

This method can return different instances for different threads, and it really does.

If you're developing multithread web application, keep in mind a few things.

1. Don't use `ThreadStaticAttribute`. It works in Windows and console applications, but it may not work in web applications, since a single request can be handled by different threads, if you use `async`, `await`, and `Task<T>`.
2. Use `HttpContext.Current.Items` instead of `ThreadStaticAttribute`. These `Items` are "static" in each `HttpContext`.
3. Use [SynchronizationContext](http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.ru/2012/12/understanding-synchronizationcontext-in.html) if you need important settings of `HttpContext` (regional settings, logged user, and your own `HttpContext.Items`) after asynchronous calls (if you're not using `await`).

The reason why you should be careful is a thread pool. It's quite possible that your asynchronous method starts to run in a first thread, continues in a second, and ends in a third. Since each thread has its own copy of the thread static field, you can get unpredictable different values of the field in different locations of your method. `SynchronizationContext` allows you to return to the initial thread with correct values of regional settings, `HttpContext.Items`, etc. The `await` operator does it work for you, so you shouldn't care about context, if you're using the `await` (thanks to @StephenCleary for the correction).

Now for the thread-static fields. When ASP.NET gets a HTTP request, it creates the new instance of `HttpContext` with empty `HttpContext.Items` collection. At the same time `ThreadStatic` fields are initialized already by previous HTTP request. Therefore f.e. a `Singleton` class, based on a thread-static field may not work properly. It's important both in synchronous and asynchronous methods of a web application.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly use `SynchronizationContext`; `await` will do so by default automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'm the little too paranoid. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko But I can't find any `ThreadStatic` attribute used inside the HttpContext.cs file. Where is it actually used?!

Comment: @rejnev I mean, you might to use ThreadStatic-fields in your code, f.e. in the domain or data-access layers. These layers can be used in your back-end, f.e. in a console application performing background data processing. ThreadStatic-fields works fine in console apps. But as soon as you start to use this code in a web app, there may be side-effects. This doesn't mean side-effects are necessarily, but they're possible. Therefore, the general rule — don't use them in domain/data-access layers, if you don't know what are you doing.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko My question is how .Net framework created the **Current** property inside the **HttpContext** class with no footprint of ThreadStatic usage! I rummaged the whole source code for that ;-)

Comment: @rejnev As I understand it, a ThreadStatic is a relativity high-level construction. Probably HttpContext attaches itself to a thread, but it does so at lower level.

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in thread-local storage, implemented with [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET. The ambient context design pattern is also relevant here.

Comment: Except for the fact that `HttpContext.Current` does not seem to use that attribute -- its implementation seems considerably more sophisticated.

Comment: Of course, a property cannot directly have ThreadStatic applied to it, only fields. But there must be thread-local storage somewhere inside it's implementation.